# How to implement an active endpoint and passive STS with in one STS?

Tags: sts-securitytokenservice, ws-trust, passive-sts

I have been struggling to find out how can I implement Active STS and Passive STS with in one STS.

Well the requirement is that I need to allow the applications to have their own login pages but they should get authentication through Custom STS that I have created. And if they use their own login page I will have to add their application using the WS-Trust relationship between their login page and my active endpoint of sts so that they pass the credentials to the webservice and get the SAML token?

Please any help will be appreciated on how to create a single STS with both passive and active  functionalities.